# chaque jour - position in the sentence

Tags: ordre-des-mots

Is there any difference among the different positions of the adverbial expression "chaque jour" in a sentence ? Example:

- Chaque jour, la police doit lutter contre le crime. (at the beginning of the sentence)
- La police doit lutter contre le crime chaque jour (at the end of the sentence)
- La police doit lutter chaque jour contre le crime. (after the verb)

Comment: They have essentially the same meaning (but things may be different in other situations). Note: 'chaque jour' feels more stilted than 'tous les jours'.

Answer (score 2):

There is even a fourth possibility.

- La police doit  chaque jour lutter contre le crime. (*usually the adverb has to be short in order to appear here, as in the following examples.*)
- La police doit parfois faire face à des imprévus.
- La police doit souvent user de la force dans de pareilles circonstances.

In my opinion, there is no difference as far as meaning goes; the only difference is in the style. The place chosen can help to make the style more fluid, which is a concern mostly when you add elements in the sentence.

- Chaque jour, la police doit lutter avec acharnement contre le crime.
- La police doit  chaque jour lutter avec acharnement contre le crime.
- La police doit lutter chaque jour avec acharnement contre le crime.
- La police doit lutter avec acharnement contre le crime  chaque jour. (*not a likely construction*)

Answer (score 1):

Le sens d'une phrase peut varier selon la position de l'adverbe. En effet, l'adverbe peut s'appliquer à des parties différentes : un adjectif, un adverbe, un verbe, ou à l'ensemble de la phrase.

> La police **lutte** *chaque jour* contre le crime.

L'adverbe renforce ici le verbe lutter : le travail de la police est difficile, ou la police est très engagée dans son travail.

> **Chaque jour,** la police lutte contre le crime.

L'adverbe agit sur l'ensemble de la phrase, il exprime une notion de fréquence : la police lutte quotidiennement ou fréquemment contre le crime (en envisageant que le crime n'est pas quotidien).

> La police doit lutter contre le crime *chaque jour*.

Dans ce cas-ci, l'adverbe ne s'applique à aucun élément de la phrase.